# if img attr scr has specific word

Tags: jquery

How to grab specific images; if images are named:

```
pc_monitor_24.jpg
mac_monitor_23.jpg
pc_mouse_23.jpg
```

by selecting only part of name?

Grabbing the textarea input like:
if entered '`pc`'

```
$('.textarea').keyup(function(){
   var getName = $(this).html();
});

$('img.imgResult').attr('src', getName+'.jpg'); // this works but only if full name entered
```

Using [~selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/)

Is it possible to retrieve the number of matched images and print them on screen?
I'll appretiate any good suggestion, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var matchingImages = $('img.imgResult[src~="' + getName + '"]');

// Now you can loop over matchingImages using e.g. $.each
// and call attr('src') to get the source for each one.
```

Answer (score 2):

There may be a more concise way to do this, but if all else fails you can always just check the `src` attribute of each one:

```
$('.textarea').keyup(function(){
    var matchingImages = [];
    var getName = $(this).html();
    jQuery.each($('img.imgResult'), function() {
        if (this.src.indexOf(getName) != -1) {
            matchingImages.push(this);
        }
    });
    alert("Found " + matchingImages.length + " images.");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

These names are started with the word you found. So start-matching selector should be used:

```
$('img.imgResult[src^="' + getName + '_"]').each(function() { /* ... */ });
```